# Вызов модального окна с картинки

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Прошу помощи. Ни каким известным мне методом не получается вызвать модальное окно при нажатии на картинку. Нужно что бы при нажатии на картинку "Заказать"- отображалась форма в модальном окне.

```css
.comf {
        margin-top: 16%;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 300px;
        height: 224px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .pre p {
        width: 301px;
        height: 226px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50.4%;
        left: 50.0%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    


    .pre p:hover,
    img:hover+p {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .pre .col-md-4>div {
      position: relative;
    }
   
    
    
    
    
    .do {
            position: relative;
    }
    
    
    
    .posle p {
        width: 301px;
        height: 226px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Scada;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 140px;
        left: 50.0%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 17px;
}
    
    .comf .do p {
        width: 300px;

        position: absolute;
        font-family: Scada;
        font-size: 17px;
        bottom: 17px;
        right: 0;
        background: rgba(28, 82, 95, 0.6);
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 29px 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 1px 4px;
    }
    


    .posle p:hover,
    img:hover+p {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .posle .col-md-4>div {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    
    .posle {
    display:none;
    }
    .comf:hover .posle {
        display:block;
    }
    .comf:hover .do {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .zakaz img {
        position: relative;
        right: 8px;
    }
    
    .uslbot {
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="comf">
                  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cvWSra/usl2.jpg">
                     
                     <div class="zakaz">
                     <img src="https://image.ibb.co/frX6jv/zakaz.png" alt="">

                     </div>
                     
                      <div class="posle"><p>Парам пам пам</p></div>
                      <div class="do"><p>Парам пам пам</p></div>
                </div>
                
                
              </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам нужно:
добавить новый тег `<div>` в которой будет форма.

```
<div class='modal' style="display:none;">
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите текст">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

На картинку мы вешаем событие: onclick = func();

```
<img onclick="func();" src="https://image.ibb.co/frX6jv/zakaz.png" alt="">
<script>
function func(){
$('.modal').css('display','block');
$('.modal').css('z-index','100500');
$('.modal').css('position','fixed');
$('.modal').css('top','0');
$('.modal').css('width','100%');
}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

конечно можете подыскать красивое оформление вашей формы и div-а в целом, но а так - скрипт рабочий